# Running PL/SQL and T-SQL Through JDBC

Tags: java, t-sql, jdbc, plsql

I'm wondering what's the best way to run a PL/SQL or T-SQL code blocks through JDBC.

To be more specific - what JDBC API should one use to execute PL/SQL or T-SQL blocks that return `ResultSet`s?

Update:

Even more specifically - I have a generic code that receives SQL code (may be SQL, PL/SQL or T-SQL) as an input, loads the appropriate JDBC driver according to the required database, and executes the given SQL code as follows:

```
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement (); 
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("BEGIN some code END SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");
  while (rs.next ()) {
     System.out.println (rset.getString (1));
  }
```

This returns no `ResultSet` when using some T-SQL or PL/SQL objects like cursors for example.

And so, I was wondering if this JDBC API is the best way to execute such queries. In case it is, then there must be a bug in the specific JDBC driver implementation i'm using.

Comment: Use `execute("your PL/SQL block here")` and then `Statement.getResultSet()`. Check the JavaDocs it even has an example for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CallableStatement` is generally the way to go. This link gives an example how to do it in Oracle:

[Using Cursor Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28765/addfunc.htm#CIHIGFFE)

Note that you get a `Cursor`, not a `ResultSet`.

In T-SQL (which I don't know well) a `CallableStatement` with `executeQuery` should work as expected, see this link:

[JDBC: CallableStatement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/callablestatement.html)

Comment: Thank you @ammoQ. will `CallableStatement` work for plain SQL code? my query is dynamic and i don't know its actual type.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure (you will have to give it a try) but the specification says that CallableStatement is for executing stored procedures, so I wouldn't expect it to work with plain SQL queries. Results probably depend on the database system and driver used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the connection information beforehand to execute the SQL. You cannot infer the database from the SQL. So I don't think there is any such API which is present to handle such queries.

You can use the standard JDBC API. An example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/basic.htm#i1008334):

```
import java.sql.*; 
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

class JdbcTest { 
   public static void main (String args []) throws SQLException { 
      // Create DataSource and connect to the local database
      OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
      ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/orcl");
      ods.setUser("scott");
      ods.setPassword("tiger");
      Connection conn = ods.getConnection();

      // Query the employee names 
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement (); 
      ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT ename FROM emp");
      // Print the name out 
      while (rset.next ())
         System.out.println (rset.getString (1));

      //close the result set, statement, and the connection
      rset.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   } 
}
```

Comment: This works fine for plain SQL but does not seem to support all T-SQL operations.

Comment: @zuckermanori:- Yes, can you be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve? You can refer [this](http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-jdbc-connection-tutorial.php) as to how you can connect to MySQL as well using JDBC.

Comment: @zuckermanori:- If I understood correctly then what you are looking for is the database info from the SQL query which is not possible, and hence I dont think there is any such API present. (*Do correct me I misunderstood it*)

Comment: you misunderstood it. i have the database info. What i want is to run a dynamic SQL code (may be SQL, PL/SQL or T-SQL) that returns results, and read these results.